# How can this heat engine be considered a reversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, heat-engine

> A heat engine operates between a body with finite heat capacity  at initial temperature $_1$ and a reservoir at fixed temperature $T_2$. Show that the maximum amount of work that can be done is given by $$ where:
>   $W=c\left|T_2-T_1\right|-cT_2\ln\left(T_2/T_1\right)$.

The way this was shown used results of a Carnot engine. From what I understand the Carnot cycle is reversible, because it operates between 2 reservoirs. Here, the body with finite heat capacity will eventually end up at a temperature of the reservoir, $T_2$.

Once this happens, how can you go back the other way? Even if you input work into the engine, you can not force heat to flow between two bodies already at the same temperature, can you? Why can we assume the results derived from considering a Carnot cycle and apply them to this question?

Comment: To be clear, which temperature is the higher?

Comment: Also, the Carnot cycle operates between two FIXED temperature reservoirs.

Comment: Assume $T_1$ is larger

Comment: @BobD So am I correct in saying we can not use the fact the efficiency of a cycle  =  $T_2/T_1$? If so I can check with my professor and ask why they used that result.

Comment: You can use the Carnot efficiency equation if the cycle is reversible, but not the value of T1 as the high temperature since it is not fixed. You would instead need to use the mean value of the temperature at which heat is added reversibly to the system.

Comment: Part of the question is exactly how such a system can be reversible?  I dont see how once the temperatures equalise, you could go back to the initial state.

Comment: Who says you can't force the heat to flow back between the two bodies already at the same temperature using an engine operating in a cycle?

Comment: To solve this problem, you already showed that the change in entropy of the adiabatic system consisting of the engine working fluid, the body, and the reservoir is equal to zero.  So the process must be reversible.

Comment: @VishalJain Is the working substance an ideal gas in your cycle?

Comment: @ChetMiller So the body (T1) , working fluid, and reservoir (T2) are all part of an adiabatic system? Not sure I follow. I thought the body (initially at T1) is a variable temperature heat source for some sort of polytropic process wherein expansion work is done partially at the expense of the internal energy of the working substance.

Comment: @BobD Yes, they are.  No heat enters or leaves this combination of three elements, although they can exchange heat with one another.  Although unstated explicitly, it is clear to me that this problem is referring to a working fluid in an engine that is operating in a cycle.  So the change in internal energy and entropy of the engine/working fluid are zero.

Comment: @ChetMiller Hmm..Very interesting. If all three are part of the same system, then all the work being done is internal to the system? Is this simply a matter of where we define the system boundary? Could my description also apply, i.e., that there is a polytropic process that can take the working fluid from T1 to T2?

Comment: @BobD It was not specified in the problem sheet

Comment: @VishalJain Other than what you posted, was there any other information in the problem sheet?

Comment: No it was not given, nor  was I expecting extra information to be needed, if required I can ask my professor for clarification.

Comment: @BobD Adiabatic means that no heat can enter or leave the system.  It doesn't say anything about work interactions with the surroundings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in entropy of the body is $c\ln{(T_2/T_1)}$ and the change in entropy of the reservoir is $Q_R/T_2$, where $Q_R$ is the heat transferred from the engine to the reservoir; the change in entropy of the engine is zero, since it is assumed to be operating in a cycle.  So the change in entropy of the combination of body, engine working fluid, and reservoir is $$\Delta S=c\ln{(T_2/T_1)}+Q_R/T_2$$If the process is carried out reversibly to give maximum work, $\Delta S=0$.  That results in the heat transferred to the reservoir as:  $$Q_R=cT_2\ln{(T_1/T_2)}$$The heat transferred from the body to the engine working fluid is $Q_H=c(T_1-T_2)$.  So the reversible work done by the system is $$W=Q_H-Q_R=c(T_1-T_2)-cT_2\ln{(T_1/T_2)}$$This assumes that $T_1>T_2$.  If $T_2>T_1$, the correct answer is the answer given in the book.